# How can I use the GAE bulkloader to upload data from multiple csv files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing my first App Engine app. I haven't yet uploaded it to appspot.com -- I am just using the development server at the moment.

I have written some models, my own `bulkloader.yaml` file, and I am currently trying to use `appcfg.py` to load my sample data into the data store (several thousand entities of two different kinds).

In this question: [uploading-data-with-bulkloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937011/uploading-data-with-bulkloader), the original poster mentions that he solved his problem by splitting the data up into multiple files. How can I do this?

At the moment I am using `appcfg.py` like this:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml   --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=mydata/objects.csv --kind=FirstObject --email=test@example.com
```

How can I add a second `filename` and `kind`? I got the impression this was possible from the example .yaml file here: [bulkloadersample.appspot.com](http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/), but it's possible that version of the bulkloader is out of date (e.g. it uses `model` instead of `kind` in the transformers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops. After stepping away from the computer for a while, the answer was obvious -- I should just make two calls to `appcfg.py`, as follows:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --kind=Model1 # more options here
```

and 
    appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --kind=Model2 # more options here

When downloading from the production server it is possible to download all the kinds in the datastore at once, but it doesn't seem like it is possible to upload or download multiple kinds in any other situations.